# "bornophagic" in cited references

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis

Could anybody come up with a cited reference for the following concept?

> A subset $B$ of a topological vector space $X$ is called "bornophagic" if, for every bounded $A\subset X$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $A\subset\delta B$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually, such sets are called *bornivorous*. E.g., in the book *Barrelled Locally Convex Spaces* of Bonet and Perez Carreras.